# How to get Key=>Value in Salt

Tags: foreach, yaml, key-value, salt-stack

in pilars i have

```
...
opt:
  miimon: 100
  updelay: 0
  downdelay: 0
  mode: 802.3ad
...
```

And i want dynamically change this in sls file

```
{% for device, args in pillar['machine_id'][grains['machine_id']]['network'].items() %}
{{device}}:
...
    {% if args['type'] == 'bond' %}
        {% if 'opt' in args %}
    - miimon: {{args['opt']['miimon']}}
    - updelay: {{args['opt']['downdelay']}}
    - downdelay: {{args['opt']['downdelay']}}
    - mode: {{args['opt']['mode']}}
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

Here what i'm search completed on php

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    echo "Key: $key; Value: $value<br />\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.

```
{% if args['type'] == 'bond' %}
  {% if 'opt' in args %}
    {% for key, value in args['opt'].iteritems() %}
- {{ key }}: {{ value }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

New in 3005 there's a filter that does this transformation for you:

```py
{% if args["type"] == "bond" %}
    {{ args.get("opt", {}) | dict_to_sls_yaml_params | indent }}
{% endif %}
```